# PHP File automatically saves blank inputs in my Database

Tags: php

Good Day, every time I refresh my php file, the successful alert always shows up, even before pressing the submit button, thus showing empty data in my DB.

I need help, since there is no warning or error shown.
Thank you in advance for helping.

PHP:

```
session_start(

);

    require 'Connect.php';

if(empty($_POST['FirstName']))
    $FirstName = '';
else
    $FirstName = ($_POST['FirstName']);
if(empty($_POST['LastName']))
    $LastName = '';
else
    $LastName = ($_POST['LastName']);
if(empty($_POST['Gender']))
    $Gender = '';
else
    $Gender = ($_POST['Gender']);
if(empty($_POST['UserName']))
    $UserName = '';
else
    $UserName = ($_POST['UserName']);
if(empty($_POST['Password']))
    $Password = '';
else
    $Password = ($_POST['Password']);
if(empty($_POST['reEnterPassword']))
    $reEnterPassword = '';
else
    $reEnterPassword = ($_POST['reEnterPassword']);
if(empty($_POST['EmailAdd']))
    $EmailAdd = '';
else
    $EmailAdd = ($_POST['EmailAdd']);
if(empty($_POST['reEnterEmailAdd']))
    $reEnterEmailAdd = '';
else
    $reEnterEmailAdd = ($_POST['reEnterEmailAdd']);

    $sql = " INSERT INTO User(FirstName, LastName, UserName, Password, reEnterPassword, EmailAdd, reEnterEmailAdd)
             VALUES ('$FirstName', '$LastName', '$UserName', '$Password', '$reEnterPassword', '$EmailAdd', '$reEnterEmailAdd'); ";

    $result = mysql_query($sql);
        if (!$result){
          die('Invalid Input: ' . mysql_error().$sql);
        }  
        else{
          echo "<script> alert('Successfully Added'); </script> ";
        }

?>
```

Comment: You need to use a conditional `isset()` wrapped around your entire executable code. You most likely have your HTML form inside the same file, something you're not showing.

Comment: You're also vulnerable to [SQL Injection](http://bobby-tables.com/)

Comment: Sidenote: You could cut down your code dramatically by using a `foreach` and an array.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

it's because you are inserting empty variables in database.

```
$FirstName = (isset($_POST['FirstName'])&&$_POST['FirstName']!='')?$_POST['FirstName']:die("required");
```

Do this for each variable. and then execute your query. It won't add empty data.

As @Machavity said, to prevent `SQL injection`. look into this:

http://php.net/manual/en/ref.pdo-mysql.php

bind your variable, rather insert it directly in your query.

Comment: The trick works. now the problem is, every time I press the submit button, the success alert doesn't show up, instead it shows "Object not Found" and still not putting the data into my DB. Any solution to that? I still don't see any warning or error showing. I'm very sorry for questioning a lot. I'm new to PHP.